# CodeIgniter 4 - How to use <?= $variable ?> syntax in an update form <select> to return record value?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I noticed that in the CodeIgniter 4 documentation there are two types of `echo's`: `<?php echo $variable; ?>` and `<?= $variable ?>`. I particularly prefer the `<?= $variable ?>`.

I have an update form, where the  fields use `value="<?= $user_hunter['name_hunter'] ?>"` to return the value, but a  I don't know how it would work anymore using `<?= ?>`.

I would like to standardize this, I know the snippet below works, but I wanted to understand how the alternative works.

```
    <div class="form_group">
        <div for="blood_type">blood_type:
                <select class="form-control" name="blood_type" required>
                        <option value="" <?php if($user_hunter['blood_type']==''){echo 'selected';}?>>Choose the blood type </option>
                            <option value="A+" <?php if($user_hunter['blood_type']=='A+'){echo 'selected';}?>>A+</option>
                            <option value="A-" <?php if($user_hunter['blood_type']=='A-'){echo 'selected';}?>>A-</option>
                            <option value="B+" <?php if($user_hunter['blood_type']=='B+'){echo 'selected';}?>>B+</option>
                            <option value="B-" <?php if($user_hunter['blood_type']=='B-'){echo 'selected';}?>>B-</option>
                            <option value="AB+" <?php if($user_hunter['blood_type']=='AB+'){echo 'selected';}?>>AB+</option>
                            <option value="AB-" <?php if($user_hunter['blood_type']=='AB-'){echo 'selected';}?>>AB-</option>
                            <option value="O+"  <?php if($user_hunter['blood_type']=='O+'){echo 'selected';}?>>O+</option>
                            <option value="O-"  <?php if($user_hunter['blood_type']=='O-'){echo 'selected';}?>>O-</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `<?= ?>`, you need to provide a *echoable* value.
In your case you want to echo the result of an `if` condition. A ternary condition would be nice.

A ternary condition is like an `if .. else` but in a single line. You can search for *Ternary Behaviour* [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

A solution with your data will be `<?= $user_hunter['blood_type'] == 'A+' ? 'selected' : '' ?>`. You can translate this condition by *if the user blood type is A+ then echo selected else echo nothing*